# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: windows, docker, gpu

I have recently installed Docker on Windows. When I try to start Docker GPU environment, I get the following message:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for intrinsick/keras-retinanet-gpu:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: segmentation fault, stdout: , stderr:: unknown.
```

Please help me get rid of this error.

Client: Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086.

Desktop:
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2

Comment: Have you tried the `getting-started` image? I have the same problem, but `getting-started` worked fine. It is my own image that gives me the error.

Comment: @verified_tinker, yes, same. Did you manage to solve it? Looks like the drivers have been installed incorrectly..

Comment: I tried on Windows and it worked. (I had previously been trying on WSL.)